# What are the differences between an iPod touch and an iPhone 4S?

Tags: ipod-touch, iphone

I see that the prices for the 64GB iPhone 4S and iPod touch are the same.

Besides having a phone as well as the monthly data fee and Siri, which I see is on the iPhone 4S, are there any other difference between the two products that I may be missing?  It looks like both use the same version of iOS.

Comment: Technically, if you want to do a comparison without the monthly fee, you should compare an unlocked iPhone with the iPod touch. From the US site, an unlocked 64GB 4S is currently $849, a large jump up from the $399 64GB iPod Touch (http://store.apple.com/us/browse/home/shop_iphone/family/iphone/iphone4s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The iPhone 4S has a much more powerful processor and better graphics performance. It's a **dual core A5 processor**, whereas the latest iPod Touch 4G still uses the **A4** processor.

You will see a better throughout system performance and have the ability to play more resource demanding games.

If you're looking for my opinion about what to buy, I recommend you buy the iPhone 4S. After all: **You can always use an iPhone as an iPod, but not vice versa.**

Comment: You could buy an Apple Peel (http://news.cnet.com/8301-17938_105-20013347-1.html) to convert an iPod Touch into a phone. No guarantees on how well it works though! ;)

Comment: @JW01 Ha! That's funny and amazing at the same time! :)